# Tabular display of output

Tags: python, python-2.7, output

What is the best method to create a neat tabular output and also save it the same way into text file ?

Right now I am displaying my output onto IPython console with the following code which provides an output as shown in Figure(1).

```
outputLine = ["NIST line   CG100    CG050    FactoryCal    HMFW (nm)-original       (SIGMA)         WCalFunctionDerivatives"]
for n, line in enumerate(wlines, 1):
    outputLine.append(" ".join(
        [str(item) for item in [wlines[n-1],peaks[n-1].cg100(),
         peaks[n-1].cgArb(0.5),
         wavelengthToPixel(wlines[n-1], 500, wavep),
         peaks[n-1].getHMFW() / prismpy.wcalfunctionDerivative(results.x, wlines[n-1]), peaks[n-1].getHMFWPixels(), prismpy.wcalfunctionDerivative(results.x, wlines[n-1])]]))
```

[image: Figure(1)]

Coming from a Mathematica background, what other methods can I use to display this same output in a neat tabular format ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are going to any analysis on this data you may want to look into `pandas`, which will tabulate data on output but its strength is in the analysis.

Comment: @AChampion : There is no further analysis to be done on this data. The final results shall be this as displayed in the figure. Nevertheless will check pandas. Do you mean DataFrame(pandas) exclusively ?

Comment: Yes, a DataFrame would hold the data and automatically convert to string and tabulate on output. But it is probably overkill just for formatting. Though another SO'er said "come for the formatting, stay for analysis", which I echo here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with a list of lists, the following approach might be useful:

```
def col_display(data, file):
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])
    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]
    for row in data:
        output = "  ".join(["%-*s" % (widths[index], col) for index, col in enumerate(row)])
        print(output)       
        file.write(output + '\n')

outputLine = ["NIST line", "CG100", "CG050", "FactoryCal", "HMFW (nm)-original", "(SIGMA)", "WCalFunctionDerivatives"]
wlines = [[123.1234567890] * 7] * 4
lines = [outputLine] + wlines

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    col_display(lines, f_output)
```

Which would display the following, and create a text file with the same contents:

```
NIST line      CG100          CG050          FactoryCal     HMFW (nm)-original  (SIGMA)        WCalFunctionDerivatives
123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789       123.123456789  123.123456789          
123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789       123.123456789  123.123456789          
123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789       123.123456789  123.123456789          
123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789  123.123456789       123.123456789  123.123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a python module exactly doing this: [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)